# Goroutines vs asyncio tasks + thread pool for CPU-bound calls

Tags: python-3.x, go, concurrency, python-asyncio, coroutine

Are goroutines roughly equivalent to python's `asyncio` tasks, with an additional feature that any CPU-bound task is routed to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of being added to the event loop (of course, with the assumption that we use a python interpreter without GIL)?

Is there any substantial difference between the two approaches that I'm missing? Of course, apart from the efficiencies and code clarity that result from the concurrency being an integral part of Go.

Comment: "any CPU-bound task is routed to its own thread" that's not how goroutines work, so I'm not sure what to make of that part of the question.

Comment: I thought go runtime dynamically changes the number of threads to ensure that goroutines don't block each other. Since an event loop can already deal with I/O-bound tasks without blocking, but cannot handle CPU-bound tasks, I concluded that an equivalent treatment would be to put CPU-bound tasks in their own threads. Perhaps I should have said "routed to a thread pool" instead of "routed to its own thread"? I edited the question to say that.

Answer (score 12):

I think I know part of the answer. I tried to summarize my understanding of the differences, in order of importance, between `asyncio` tasks and goroutines:

1) Unlike under `asyncio`, one rarely needs to worry that their goroutine will block for too long. OTOH, memory sharing across goroutines is akin to memory sharing across threads rather than `asyncio` tasks since goroutine execution order guarantees are much weaker (even if the hardware has only a single core).

`asyncio` will only switch context on explicit `await`, `yield` and certain event loop methods, while Go runtime may switch on far more subtle triggers (such as certain function calls). So `asyncio` is perfectly cooperative, while goroutines are only mostly cooperative (and the roadmap suggests they will become even less cooperative over time).

A really tight loop (such as with numeric computation) could still block Go runtime (well, the thread it's running on). If it happens, it's going to have less of an impact than in python - unless it occurs in mutliple threads.

2) Goroutines are have off-the-shelf support for parallel computation, which would require a more sophisticated approach under `asyncio`.

Go runtime can run threads in parallel (if multiple cores are available), and so it's somewhat similar to running multiple `asyncio` event loops in a thread pool under a GIL-less python runtime, with a language-aware load balancer in front.

3) Go runtime will automatically handle blocking syscalls in a separate thread; this needs to be done explicitly under `asyncio` (e.g., using  `run_in_executor`).

That said, in terms of memory cost, goroutines are very much like `asyncio` tasks rather than threads.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could think of it working that way underneath, sure.  It's not really accurate, but, close enough.

But there is a big difference: in Go you can write straight line code, and all the I/O blocking is handled for you automatically.  You can call Read, then Write, then Read, in simple straight line code.  With Python asyncio, as I understand it, you need to queue up a function to handle the reads, rather than just calling Read.

Comment: Thx! Does my self-answer have any significant misunderstandings? 

And yes, in python you either need to use an asynchronous IO library, or if it's not available, you need to explicitly send the IO operations to a thread pool (this can be streamlined by getting back a future so that it doesn't break the asynchronous code style). A naive call to synchronous blocking IO would hang the event loop.

Comment: It's true that the Go runtime spins up new threads as needed.  I'm not sure quite what to say when comparing goroutines with async I/O functions.  They are really different, so when you say that the two approaches are equivalent, I would say that that is only true under a very loose interpretation.

Comment: No, in python asyncio you can do something like `await stream_reader.read(num_bytes)` which really isn't very different from `file.read(num_bytes` in the blocking world